# The Chat thing on the mainpage

Tags: feature-request, design

The main page has a box about the [chat thingie](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). No one seems to be using it for anything---I just went into the "room" and it appears the last time someone said something there was 10 days ago... Could it be moved somewhere less prominent? The main page is quite busy already!

(The tag list and the recently-awarded-badge list are also sort of pointless IMHO... When I asked about them on MO, they were removed and I don't think anyone even noticed.)

Answer (score 5):

Really? Looks like it was active fairly recently to me. Perhaps you should look again? :)

We like to keep the design elements in familiar places across the network, but if you wish them to be removed, it's very easy to set up [a user script](https://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts) that hides those elements in the CSS so you don't have to see them.

Comment: According to the thing itself, someone said something 10 days ago, then you quoted this question, made a comment for moderators and Willie said something. Yes. Really :)

Comment: Irony doesn't always come across well over the internet.  I was initially confused by the first line, too.

Comment: @Jonas, it would not have been the first counterfactual claim around here... In that context, big IRONY signs are quite helpful!